# Pegar campo de um formulário html, para fazer uma query SQL( com nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

Boa tarde a todos!

Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho um formulário HTML, com 2 campos de input( Data Inicial e Data Final) e um botão de buscar logo abaixo. Após esse formulário tenho uma tabela só com o cabeçalho dos campos que eu quero

Estou trabalhando com nodeJS e view engine EJS. Preciso de uma forma quando a pessoa, passar as datas no formulário e apertar o botão de buscar, monte a minha querySQL e jogue o resultado na tabela.

Meu código HTML está assim :

```
                <form action="/principal" method="post">
               
                <input type="number" id="codigoMedico" name="codigoMedico" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu código" maxlength="5"><br></label><br> -->
                <label for="datePickerInicial">Data Inicial:</label>
                <input id="datePickerInicial" name="dataPickerInicial" class="form-control DataInicial" width="200">
                
                <br>
                <label for="datePickerFinal">Data Final:</label>
                <input id="datePickerFinal" name="dataPickerFinal" class="form-control DataFinal" width="200">
                
                <br>
                <button id="btnBuscar"class="btn btn-success" >Buscar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <br>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>Paciente</th>
                <th>Idade</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Convênio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
```

e meu arquivo js está assim :

```
<code>

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const connection = require("./database/database");

//View engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Static
app.use(express.static('public'));

//body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get("/principal", (req,res) => {
    res.render("principal")
});

app.post("/principal", (req,res) => {

const dataInicial = req.body.dataPickerInicial;
const dataFinal = req.body.dataPickerFinal;

const dataInicialValor = dataInicial.value;
const dataFinalValor = dataFinal.value;

connection.raw(`select a.cd_pessoa_fisica,
    (select a.cd_pessoa_fisica from tasy.agenda a where a.cd_agenda = c.cd_agenda) AS cd_pessoa_fisica, to_char(c.dt_agenda,'dd/mm/yyyy') as data, to_char(c.dt_agenda, 'hh24:mm') as hora, c.nr_minuto_duracao, 
    c.nm_paciente, c.qt_idade_pac, 
    c.nr_telefone, tasy.obter_desc_convenio(nvl(c.cd_convenio,0)) as convenio, 
    CASE WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.dt_confirmacao is NULL THEN 'N' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.dt_confirmacao IS NOT NULL THEN 'C' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.nr_atendimento IS NOT NULL THEN 'EA' 
    WHEN c.IE_ENCAIXE ='S' THEN 'EN' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.IE_ENCAIXE <>'S' THEN 'N' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='F' or c.ie_status_agenda ='I' THEN 'F' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='AD' THEN 'EA' 
    ELSE 
    c.ie_status_agenda END AS ie_status_agenda, 
    CASE WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.dt_confirmacao is NULL THEN 'Marcada' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.dt_confirmacao IS NOT NULL THEN 'Confirmada' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.nr_atendimento IS NOT NULL THEN 'Em atendimento' 
    WHEN c.IE_ENCAIXE ='S' THEN 'Encaixe' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='N' AND c.IE_ENCAIXE <>'S' THEN 'Marcada' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='F' or c.ie_status_agenda ='I' THEN 'Falta' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='E' THEN 'Executada' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='AC' THEN 'Aguardando consulta' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='A' THEN 'Aguardando' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='O' THEN 'Em Agenda' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='B' THEN 'Bloqueada' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='C' THEN 'Cancelada' 
    WHEN c.ie_status_agenda ='AD' THEN 'Em atendimento' 
    ELSE 
    'Marcada' END AS status_agenda, 
    im_pessoa_fisica, 
    c.ds_observacao, 
    CASE WHEN p.IE_SEXO='F' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS TIPSEX 
    from tasy.agenda_consulta c 
    JOIN tasy.agenda a ON a.cd_agenda = c.cd_agenda 
    LEFT JOIN tasy.pessoa_fisica_foto f ON f.CD_PESSOA_FISICA=c.CD_PESSOA_FISICA 
    LEFT JOIN tasy.pessoa_fisica p ON p.CD_PESSOA_FISICA=c.CD_PESSOA_FISICA 
    where trunc(c.dt_agenda) between TO_DATE('${dataInicialValor}' , 'yyyy/mm/dd') and  TO_DATE('${dataFinalValor}', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    and c.cd_pessoa_fisica is not null 
    AND a.cd_pessoa_fisica =  53881
    and c.ie_status_agenda <> 'C' order by c.dt_agenda`).then(medicos => {
       res.render("principal", {
        medicos : medicos
       }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
       })
    })

});
```

Answer (score -3):

Dentro da tag tbody podes usar um ciclo para preencher as linhas da tabela com os médicos.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < medicos.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= medicos[i].ie_status_agenda %></td>
        <td><%= medicos[i].data %></td>
        <td><%= medicos[i].hora %></td>
        <td><%= medicos[i].nm_paciente %></td>
        <td><%= medicos[i].qt_idade_pac %></td>
        <td><%= medicos[i].nr_telefone %></td>
        <td><%= medicos[i].convenio %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```